# jQUery - Table manipulation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How would it be possible to to change the table within the **row value** into multiple columns by using jQuery? The different rows should get tr-tags added on there ends if it's a ending td-tag. To summarize, there are multiple rows in one column, but I need one row per column... I don't have a clue where to start with jQUery to fix that issue :/

Thanks a lot in advance :)

```
<table class="search">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="field"><div title="Special">Special</div</td>
         <td class="value">
            <input name="f[sp_se_s][0]" value="0" type="hidden">
            <table>
               <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                       <input id="sp_se_s_sp_se_1" value="sp_se_1" name="f[sp_se_s][sp_se_1]" type="checkbox">
                       <label for="sp_se_s_sp_se_1">Option 1</label>
                    </td> 

                    **//HERE I need a </tr><tr>**

                    <td valign="top">
                       <input id="sp_se_s_sp_se_2" value="sp_se_2" name="f[sp_se_s][sp_se_2]" type="checkbox">
                       <label for="sp_se_s_sp_se_2">Option 2</label>
                    </td>

                    **//HERE I need a </tr><tr>**

                    <td valign="top">
                       <input id="sp_se_s_sp_se_3" value="sp_se_3" name="f[sp_se_s][sp_se_3]" type="checkbox">
                       <label for="sp_se_s_sp_se_3">Option 3</label>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                       <input id="sp_se_s_sp_se_4" value="sp_se_4" name="f[sp_se_s][sp_se_4]" type="checkbox">
                       <label for="sp_se_s_sp_se_4">Option 4</label>
                    </td>

                    **//HERE I need a </tr><tr>**

                    <td valign="top">
                       <input id="sp_se_s_sp_se_16" value="sp_se_16" name="f[sp_se_s][sp_se_16]" type="checkbox">
                       <label for="sp_se_s_sp_se_16">Option 5</label>
                    </td>

                    **//HERE I need a </tr><tr>**

                    <td valign="top">
                       <input id="sp_se_s_sp_se_5" value="sp_se_5" name="f[sp_se_s][sp_se_5]" type="checkbox">
                       <label for="sp_se_s_sp_se_5">Option 6</label>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
     </tr>  
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry, But I couldn't get your question

Comment: your question is not clear, can you elaborate little more

Comment: Clue is explained as code fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution, in my mind, would be to get the contents inside of the `<tr>` elements, store them in a variable, remove the `<tr>` elements from the table and restore the `<td>` elements.

At this point in time, you will be left with a `<tbody>` element with a whole lot of `<td>` elements. From that point on, it's a matter of wrapping all the `<td>` elements in a `<tr>` element.

Off the top of my head, the jQuery syntax could look something like this:

```
var contents = $("table").find("tr").contents().detach();
$("table").find("tr").remove();
$("table tbody").html(contents);
$("table tbody").find("td").wrap("<tr></tr>");
```

Here is a Fiddle demonstrating the above in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ydsg9/46/

Answer (score 1):

The [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method seems like something what can be useful for You

You can for example get all `<td>` elements, `.wrap` it with `<tr>` and `.append()` inside new table or at the end of current one